# Displaying data in a HighCharts pie chart - Visual Studio Web app

Tags: jquery, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

This is the part of code that provides data for the chart( in the View)

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Some Chart Title',
        data:   @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))             

    }]
```

This is the code which comes in the html source code when app is executed

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Some Chart Title',
        data:   [{"Label":"Item A","Value":65},{"Label":"Item B","Value":58},   {"Label":"Item C","Value":30},{"Label":"Item D","Value":60},{"Label":"Item E","Value":65}]
```

The chart is not getting displayed properly. How do I convert the above data in necessary format?

Answer (score 0):

From the demo on the [highchart website](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic), the format for Highcharts 3.0 is

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
```